# Accessing endIcon property from TreeItem event in React Material-UI

Tags: material-ui, treeview

My TreeItems are links that open up images in a modal component. Id like to use the `endIcon` property to display a `CircularProgress` when the image is being loaded, then unload after the image is loaded. I use `OnLabelClick` event to get the image, but in the object event.target properties I see nothing that would give me access to that TreeItems's `endIcon`.
How would I get it?